# Regex with if statement

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement

Is there a way to include an if statement in a regular expression, in javascript.  This sort of thing:

```
var regex = /"if followed by [0-9] then match [a-m], else match [n-z]"/i
```

so:

```
"a9" //returns a match
"aa" //doesn't return a match
"na" //returns a match
```

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance

Comment: **Yes.** But is it only two characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly an `if`, but an alternation and look-ahead are what you need in this case:

```
([a-m](?=[0-9])|[n-z](?![0-9]))
```

Here is a working [example](https://regex101.com/r/tY4uA1/1).

Answer (score 1):

You would need this:

```
([a-m][0-9])|([n-z][a-m])
```

Or, if that is full of alphabets, then:

```
([a-m][0-9])|([n-z][a-z])
```

For the given input, it gives:

```
MATCH 1
1.  `a9`
MATCH 2
2.  `na`
```

Check online at [**RegEx 101**](https://regex101.com/r/nV5gC8/1).

**Working**

[image]

**Explanation**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent to `if` in regex is the alternation, `|`, where the regex will match as far as it can in a branch of the alternation, and try to match the next one(s) if it fails.

To code your exact statement in regex, one would use `(?=.[0-9])[a-m]|[n-z]` where you use lookahead to check the condition.

However you can use this much simpler regex :

```
[a-m][0-9]|[n-z]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP was giving an example with this little 2 char thing

Comment: Well he can use the lookahead solution in any context : check with lookahead, match what you want, alternate to specify an "else" block. However I don't think you should be thinking this way in regex, it won't help you much